# How to fix an adb offline device without connecting to usb

Tags: android, adb

I've got an android device that was previously connecting over tcp, and later on when I tried to connect `adb devices` said it was offline. Is there a way I can fix this issue without connecting over usb?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that if I disconnect/reconnect from wifi, the error goes away! I did this by moving the phone out of range of the router, and back in.